# Metric Tensor and Strain Rate Tensor- Comparison of Units

Tags: relativity, tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics

Is there any way the metric tensor can have a dimension in general relativity? I ask because there is an equation where the strain rate tensor of continuum mechanics is expressed as a difference of metric tensors in the deformed and undeformed configurations. So, the unit of the strain rate tensor is 1/length, so for the equation to hold, wouldn't the metric tensor's units also have to be 1/length ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have some four-vector $v$, then the norm of $v$ is given by:

$$ v^2 = g_{\alpha\beta}v^{\alpha}v^{\beta} $$

Since the dimensions of the left and right sides must agree this shows the metric tensor is dimensionless.

Comment: So, what about the strain rate tensor in continuum mechanics?

Comment: @nihal: in continuum mechanics the strain rate tensor $\varepsilon$ is related to the metric tensor $g$ by $\varepsilon_{ij}=dg_{ij}/dt$. Since $g$ is dimensionless the dimensions of the right side are $T^{-1}$, and this is also the dimensions of strain rate.